# Typescript: `let result: { [key: T[K]]: T } = {};` is not working, how can I type my object based on generics?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, types

I want to type a simple function called `keyBy`.

What this function do is to convert an `array of objects` into `object` based on provided 'key string':

```
const arr = [{ name: 'Jason', age: 18 }, { name: 'Amy', age: 25 }];

console.log(keyBy(arr, 'name'));

// => { 'Jason': { name: 'Jason', age: 18 }, 'Amy': { name: 'Amy', age: 25 } }
```

Now, here is a simple correct javascript implementation without typescript.

```
function keyBy(arr, key) {
  let result = {};

  arr.forEach(obj => {
    result[obj[key]] = obj;
  });

  return result;
}
```

Right now, below is my typescript version of `keyBy` (not compiling):

```js
function keyBy<T, K extends keyof T>(arr: T[], key: K): { [key: T[K]]: T } {

  // typescript yells: An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'number'.

  let result: { [key: T[K]]: T } = {};

  arr.forEach(item => {
    result[item[key]] = item;
  });

  return result;
}
```

Here is the screenshot of my VSCode:

[image]

How can I type this `keyBy` function correctly?

Comment: The value of `name: 'Jason'` does not exist in the type system, so there is no way to make that strongly typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In think you can do in some other way too:

```
export type Omit<A extends object, K extends keyof A> = Pick<A, Exclude<keyof A, K>>

type KeyOf<T extends Array<any>> = { [K: string]: Omit<T[number], 'name'> };

type Result = KeyOf<[{ name: 'a', attr: 42 }, { name: 'b', attr: 42}, {name: 'c', attr: 42}]>
```

Omit util will return interface without one key, in this case 'name'.

`T[number]` when T extends Array will return X

And K always be a string because if ordinary object.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20type%20Omit%3CA%20extends%20object%2C%20K%20extends%20keyof%20A%3E%20%3D%20Pick%3CA%2C%20Exclude%3Ckeyof%20A%2C%20K%3E%3E%0A%0Atype%20KeyOf%3CT%20extends%20Array%3Cany%3E%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BK%3A%20string%5D%3A%20Omit%3CT%5Bnumber%5D%2C%20'name'%3E%20%7D%3B%0A%0Atype%20Result%20%3D%20KeyOf%3C%5B%7B%20name%3A%20'a'%2C%20attr%3A%2042%20%7D%2C%20%7B%20name%3A%20'b'%2C%20attr%3A%2042%7D%2C%20%7Bname%3A%20'c'%2C%20attr%3A%2042%7D%5D%3E)

Comment: Glad to hear, if you want me to explain something write a comment :)

Answer (score 2):

To use named key properties, you need `in` rather than `:`:

```
{ [key in K]: T }
```

You also need to use `K`, which is a string union type of property names, not `T[K]`, which is the value of the property.

Comment: Thank you, I want to ask another question, so `K` is `'name' | 'age'` string union type right now, what will `[key in K]` become?